# can one company join two iOS Developer Programs with different Apple IDs?

Tags: ios, iphone

The situation is like this: an Existing Apple ID is being used to publish entertainment apps. Now we(from a different department of the same company) are going to release some serious business apps. We want our serious apps be released under a more serious Developer name(thus different from the existing one). What should we do? Is it possible/allowed to register a new Apple ID and join iOS Developer Program with the same company identity?

Thanks for any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

"Developer Name" is established in iTunes Connect when initially creating the account. You can't change it later, so you're probably stuck with two different accounts.

Comment: Then the question is: can I use the same legal entity to join two iOS Developer Programs with two Apple IDs?

Answer (score -2):

In IOS portal of Apple Developer Website, you can create as many app IDs as you want, and obviously each app ID will be unique like com.companyname.app1, com.companyname.app2.
So your so called serious Developers should use different APP id to publish app.

Comment: -1, question asked about Apple IDs (the ones you log in with), not App IDs.

Comment: The Answer is NO, because they are already given a mechanism to do this by using different app IDs.

Comment: Nope, since the poster is referring to the "Developer name" as being the developer that shows up in the App Store listing, and doesn't want anyone who views one of their business apps and then taps to see all apps from the same developer to see the game apps. That requires multiple developer accounts, and at least two different Apple IDs.

Comment: Will Apple allow me to use the same legal entity to join two iOS Developer Programs with two Apple IDs?

Comment: Check the Apple Developer Forums; if there's not already a thread on this there, contact Apple and ask them.